# Understanding the ModelView Matrix

Tags: opengl, matrix, transformation

I want to analyze the each component of my `4*4` ModelView Matrix.

I came to know that the starting `3*3` of ModelView Matrix stores `rotation`.
[image: Rotation]

If i want my object to have no rotation with respect to camera so My ModelView Matrix looks like this
[image]

How to change my `ModelView` Matrix if i want to have **NO Translation or Scaling** ? Can anyone explain the Maths behind this

Comment: Did a few seconds of googling for you. Hope [this](http://www.codinglabs.net/article_world_view_projection_matrix.aspx) helps.

Comment: [and this](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/) and [this](http://www.3dgep.com/3d-math-primer-for-game-programmers-matrices/)